# Shutter speed control for QX10

Tags: camera, sony

At the moment it seems it's only possible to directly set ISO on the QX10. There are a lot of applications where being able to set shutter speed directly would be very helpful. I was wondering if there is any way to do this, and, if not, if there were plans to implement this feature in the future.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about photography.  This forum is for programming-related questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a feature requestfor a Sony product.

Answer (score -1):

In the current Lens Style Cameras, only QX100 camera supports Shutter speed API. Please check 'Supported API groups' table in the API Reference document for additional details.
Best Regards,
Prem, Developer World Team